# How to finish join for this situation?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two datasets A and B.

A is likes:

```
Product ID      Version      Design_type
   1               1            a
   1               1            b
   2               2            z
   2               3            x
   3               1            c
```

B is like this:

```
Product ID      Version      Chem
   1               1            1
   1               1            2
   1               1            3
   1               2            1
   2               2            1
   2               2            2
   2               3            10
   2               3            17
   3               1            1
   3               1            2
```

The table I want to create should be like this:

```
Product ID      Version      Design_type   Chem
   1               1            a           1
   1               1            a           2
   1               1            a           3
   1               1            b           1
   1               1            b           2
   1               1            b           3
   2               2            z           1
   2               2            z           2
   2               3            x          10 
   2               3            x          17
   3               1            c           1
   3               1            c           2
```

I want to join table A and B using `Product ID` and `Version`. As long as `Product ID` and `Version` in table B matches the value in table A, all `Chem` should be attached for each `Design_type`.

I failed using `cross join`, `left join`, `outer join` in ORACLE SQL.

I appreciate every answer. Thank you.

Comment: _I failed using ..._ So [edit] your question and post the SQL you tried so that people can help you correct it.

Comment: Product ID and Version are duplicated in both tables so I am not sure what sense the results will make.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a simple `inner join`:

```
select a.*, b.chem
from a
inner join b on a.product_id = b.product_id and a.version = b.version
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=aa8da8c7edb03750a274031614a2bce3)**:

```
Product_ID | Version | Design_type | chem
---------: | ------: | :---------- | ---:
         1 |       1 | a           |    1
         1 |       1 | a           |    2
         1 |       1 | a           |    3
         1 |       1 | b           |    1
         1 |       1 | b           |    2
         1 |       1 | b           |    3
         2 |       2 | z           |    1
         2 |       2 | z           |    2
         2 |       3 | x           |   10
         2 |       3 | x           |   17
         3 |       1 | c           |    1
         3 |       1 | c           |    2
```